# Adding a new network interface tab/adapter?

Tags: .net, c, winapi

How to add a new network interface adapter/tab via coding?
like VPN clients do...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have googled it but didn't find anything...looked at pinvoke to find a win32 api that does it but no luck so a hint is apprecited